# How to test a function in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I write a small function which accept a string type variable as parameter.

I am wondering if there is any way I can test my function?

I don't want to use Unit Test thing because it is overkill.

Thank you for your responses.

**UPDATE**

Thanks all for your replies.

My case is, this function will be trigger by an event handler. However, I don't want to bind the handle with my function and I just want to check if that function works.

So the best way is to write a unit test?

Comment: You should write unit tests.

Comment: "I want to test something, but I don't want to use the tool that ships with Visual Studio that is expressly designed to run test cases". You are wrong, it's not overkill.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `immediate window` and type the function call in there to test.  Typically, one would use this thing while running an application, but it is also available at design time.

Comment: Actually, you can use the immediate window at design time. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: Learn something new every day.

Comment: Nice! I thought intermediate window could be used only during run time. Just learned that I can just copy and paste my whole function into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Thats what unit tests are for. The other option is simply create a new console test to reference it, however simply right clicking on it and creating a new unit test is easy, and the best method - it is not overkill and takes 5 seconds : )

Worst case just delete your test when its done.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a sample application that uses your function and then use the debugger to step through it and verify that everything is working correctly.

But I have to agree with SLaks - you should write unit tests. In fact, that kind of method sounds like it is begging for some unit testing.

Comment: sounds very different than my approach : )

Answer (score 0):

I would use nunit and create a class library and write unit tests to test the functions. A traditional way to quick test it is to use a console app, but this is no longer recommended as unit testing is seen as quick and more resiliant way to test code.